# rails does create twice when there is no record in a certain model unexpectedly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

### Guess

it's strange that it certainly occurs when there is no record in the database.

### What I tried

I doubted that the cause was actually ajax so I all removed `remote:true` but it hardly worked.
   controller

```
def create
  @sell = current_user.orders.build(sell_params)
  @buy = current_user.orders.build(buy_params)
  if @sell.save
    flash[:success] = 'your order has successfully submitted.'
    notify_order(@sell.rate, @sell.amount, @sell.order_type)

    @sell.rate.present? ? @sell.update(order_type: 'limit_sell') : @sell.update(order_type: 'market_sell')

    fund = Fund.create_with(amount: 0, crypto_address_id: 1)
            .find_or_create_by(user_id: current_user.id, kind: @sell.pair.split('_').last)
    fund.update(in_use: @sell.rate * @sell.amount) if @sell.order_type == 'limit_sell'
    # try to make orders done
    market_checker(@sell.pair)
  else
    if Order.where(order_status: 'done', pair: params[:order][:pair]).present?
      @currency_price = Sell.where(trading_status: 'done', currency_id: Currency.find_by_slug(params[:sell][:currency_id]).id)
      @currency_price.present? ? @currency_price = @currency_price.last.price : @currency_price = ''
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Unfortunately, there is no trading right now so that we can't show you the chart"
    end
    @pair = params[:order][:pair].to_s
    render :new
  end

  if @buy.save
    flash[:success] = 'your order has successfully submitted.'

    notify_order(@buy.rate, @buy.amount, @buy.order_type)

    @buy.rate.present? ? @buy.update(order_type: 'limit_buy') : @buy.update(order_type: 'market_buy')

    fund = Fund.create_with(amount: 0, crypto_address_id: 1).find_or_create_by(user_id: current_user.id, kind: @buy.pair.split('_').last)
    fund.update(in_use: @buy.rate * @buy.amount) if @buy.order_type == 'limit_buy'

    # try to make orders done
    market_checker(@buy.pair)
  else
    if Order.where(order_status: 'done', pair: params[:order][:pair]).present?
      @currency_price = Sell.where(trading_status: 'done', currency_id: Currency.find_by_slug(params[:sell][:currency_id]).id)
      @currency_price.present? ? @currency_price = @currency_price.last.price : @currency_price = ''
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Unfortunately, there is no trading right now so that we can't show you the chart"
    end
    @pair = params[:order][:pair].to_s
    render :new
  end
end
```

model

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validate :deposited_btc_enough?
  validate :insufficient?
  validates :amount, format: { with: /\A\d+(?:\.\d{0,8})?\z/ }, numericality: { greater_than: 0.000000009, less_than: 100_000_000 }, presence: true
  validate :rate_check
  validates :rate, format: { with: /\A\d+(?:\.\d{0,8})?\z/ }, numericality: { greater_than: 0.000000009, less_than: 100_000_000 }, if: :rate_present?
  validate :checking_order_type

  def rate_present?
    rate.present?
  end

  def checking_order_type
    if order_type == 'sell_limit' || order_type == 'buy_limit'
      errors.add(:Please, 'specify the rate of your order.') unless rate.present?
    end
    if order_type == 'sell_market' || order_type == 'buy_market'
      errors.add(:You, "can't specify the rate of your order.") if rate.present?
    end
  end

  def deposited_btc_enough?
    if rate.present?
      if rate.to_d > '0'.to_d && amount > 0
        deposited_amount = user.fund.amount if user.fund.amount.present?
        amount = rate.to_d * amount.to_s.to_d
        if deposited_amount.present?
          if coin_to_satoshi(amount).to_i > coin_to_satoshi(deposited_amount).to_i
            errors.add(:Your, 'deposited yen is short to order.')
          end
        else
          errors.add(:You, "haven't deposited yen  yet or Your transaction hasn't confirmed yet.")
        end
      else
        errors.add(:You, "can't specify negative numbers here.")
      end
    end
  end

  def to_param
    uuid
  end

  def insufficient?
    if amount.present? && order_type.split('_').last == 'sell'
      if CurrencyUser.find_by(user_id: user.id, currency_id: Pair.find_by(name: pair).currency_id).amount < amount
        errors.add(:amount, 'of this order is more than your holdings.')
        errors[:base] << 'Errors that are related to this order exist.'
      end
    end
  end

  def is_number?(string)
    true if Float(string)
  rescue StandardError
    false
  end

  def rate_check
    if rate.present?
      errors.add(:You, 'can only specify numbers') unless is_number?(rate)
      errors.add(:You, "can't specify the rate as a negative number.") unless '0'.to_d < rate.to_d
    end
  end
```

end

form

```
 <%= form_for(@sell,remote:true) do |f| %>
          <% if @sell.errors.any? %>
              <div id="error_explanation" class="alert alert-danger">
                <h2><%= @sell.errors.count %>error(s) exist(s).</h2>
                <ul>
                  <% @sell.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                      <li><%= msg %></li>
                  <% end %>
                </ul>
              </div>
          <% end %>

          <%= f.hidden_field :pair,value:@pair%>

          <%= f.hidden_field :order_type,value:"market_sell"%>

          <p>amount whatever you want to sell like 100</p>
          <div class="input-group">
            <%= f.number_field :amount, class: 'form-control form-group',placeholder:"amount"%>
          </div>
          <%= f.submit 'done', class: "btn btn-large bg-info" %>
      <% end %><br>


     <%= form_for(@buy,remote:true)do |f| %>
        <% if @buy.errors.any? %>
          <div id="error_explanation" class="alert alert-danger">
            <h2><%= @buy.errors.count %>error(s) exist(s).</h2>
            <ul>
              <% @buy.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                  <li><%= msg %></li>
              <% end %>
            </ul>
          </div>
        <% end %>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please use Rubocop and Auto-indent in your editor. You code has been reformatted with those 2 items for better readability.  See https://atom.io/packages/auto-indent  and https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop

Answer (score 0):

Your create method has way too much complexity and I'm assuming you have not written this method with test driven development because you would have broken it down into smaller methods if you had, likely moving more of the logic to the model.  I also hope this is not how your code style looks in real life.  At first glance, I'm assuming your problem is this:

```
 def create
   # why are you creating 2 orders??  Can you change this:
   @sell=current_user.orders.build(sell_params)
   @buy=current_user.orders.build(buy_params)

   #to something more like:

   @order = order_from_params
   #...omitting rest of this code because it needs a lot of refactoring.
 end

private 

def order_from_params
  #you should probably only deal with 1 order at a time either buy or sell
  # you must have a field in orders table to indicate buy or sell, probably int?
  if sell_params.present?
    @order = current_user.orders.build(sell_params)
  else
    @order = current_user.orders.build(buy_params)
  end
end
```

Then you'll need to simplify the logic in create method since you only have one model to deal with.  You should NOT rely on nor do 2 `if @order.save` inside the create action since you should again only be creating 1 order at a time.  This should get you headed in the right direction.  And if you're not doing test driven development, you're gonna have a lot worse problems then what you  have already.

Comment: First, I have to check if an order is "buy" or "sell", but there is a concern that a hidden value in a form will be forged, so I created two types of instances, I know I should place logic into models, but now I'm quickly making the core of the service, so there is no capacity to do refactoring, to answer if I do test, I had just been testing if orders are all dealt with stock-like trading, but after I started changing functions, I have never done test